# groovy while loop syntax assigning and checking a variable

Tags: syntax, groovy, loops

I was reading a blog post and saw a groovy snippet that looked lik

```
while ( entry = inputStream.nextEntry ) {
  // do something
}
```

In the while loop, is this groovy syntax that will cause the loop to break when entry is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it will probably make the compiler complain about
a possible accidental assignment. A better practise is:

`while ((entry = inputStream.nextEntry )!=null) {}`

Comment: No complaint for the compiler though.

Answer (score 0):

First week using Groovy and wanted to test this out.  Thought I would share the test & results.  Thanks for pointing this out.

```
def list = ['one', 'two', null, 'four']
def it = list.iterator()
def i
while (i = it.next()) {
    println i
}


Result: one
two
```